# Google Maps Working locally but not on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, heroku, react-google-maps

I deployed a react app to heroku but the map is not showing. I get these error messages:

`Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys util.js:248:12`

When I tried including it in both the library and loading it with script tags in index.html, I get:

`You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys`

Note: Key Restrictions are set to none.I wonder why it works from localhost but not from heroku

Answer (score 2):

google maps allowed you to access google maps without API Key only if your site are in "localhost" (because it's development mode and "only" got traffick from developer), [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) what do you need